# Evaluate the limit containing the product function

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> Evaluate $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1} \frac{\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^n(x^k+1)-2^n}{x-1}$$

We can see that there is $x-1$ in denominator, so in order to calculate the limit we have to made it disappear from the denominator. I have learnt that in these type of cases we have to factor both numerator and denominator and then cancel the expression which is becoming $0$ on putting the limiting value. But here I'm not able to factor the terms. Moreover, I opened the product function but couldn't make any good use of it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: One fun way might be to use induction. If $f_{n}(x)=\prod_{1}^n (1+x^k),$ then $$f_{n+1}(x)-2^{n+1}=(x^{n+1}+1)f_n(x)-2^{n+1}=\left(x^{n+1}-1\right)f_n(x)+2\left(f_n(x)-2^{n}\right).$$
Then divide both sides by $x-1$ to get a recurrence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\prod_{k=1}^n(x^k+1)-2^n}{x-1}&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\prod_{k=1}^n((1+h)^k+1)-2^n}h\\&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\prod_{k=1}^n(2+kh)-2^n}h\\&=2^{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^nk\\&=2^{n-2}n(n+1).\end{align}$$

Comment: Can you pls add some more details like how you transformed the original expression into another expression and which standard formulas you used

Comment: Hi, this question has been asked and answered many times here, including [one asked only 19 hours ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4528931/limit-involving-product). Please search for duplicates before answering the question.

Comment: Hi, so did I many times today for other questions, but for that one I didn't manage to find.